# Icon iphone apps

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is it possible to programmatically get access to the icon of other apps installed on an iPhone?

For example: if I need Instagram's icon, is it possible to display it in my app by accessing the icon in the Instagram bundle?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you have to find the icon if you want to use it.

Nevertheless, you have an instagram-sdk for iOs. Maybe you should look at this.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to access anything in other app bundles, but you can find the icons on the web if you know the URL. The icon images are in the app store page, which can be reached by (for example) [here](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8). The URL is subject to change, so saving a copy to your own app bundle would be the best way to ensure access to them.

http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/060/Purple/v4/76/94/e2/7694e29c-3060-9f8e-0135-cbeea67ec3af/mzl.qmyfwfsq.175x175-75.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the icon somewhere else. If it's specifically Instagram you can get it from their SDK, but for the mostpart, you'll need to find it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you'll have to keep a set of icons in your own app, which you can show to the user at a certain point. But I'm sure you cannot access the icon of an app installed on the phone like that!