# Unofficial API - Access other apps bundle and icons - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004087/iphone-app-how-to-get-app-icon-from-app-id) which pulls the app from the internet and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138576/icon-iphone-apps) which is what I'm looking for, but I'm not publishing to the app store.

So is there a way to do the following:

Go into app bundles on the device and extract the icons for those apps using official and/or unofficial APIs ?

As @Gavin specified: Jailbreaking is not an option for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps are sandboxed on iOS, so even if you're not submitting to the app store, your app is still prevented from accessing files outside your sandbox, which includes the files of other apps on the device.

Now if you wanted to jailbreak your device, you could access files outside of the sandbox. But you didn't state that you were willing to do that, so I am assuming this is out of the question for you.

Comment: Jailbreaking is not an option for me, you are correct. So my app is sandboxed right down the physical filesystem, it's not just read-only. Correct?

Comment: Correct. Your app is sandboxed. You can't even modify the contents of the app. When you save files using your app, they go in a separate folder from where your app is actually stored, because while you can read your app's files (resources and such), you can't modify them.